# Checking Input to a Custom Directive in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

I have a very large form, which was getting difficult to read and follow when editing the HTML. I decided that I would try and make the most of AngularJS and use custom directives to compress the amount of repeated text. Here is the original directive I wrote:

```
app.directive("formField", function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            fieldData: '=field',
            fieldName: '=name',
            fieldType: '=type'
        },
        template: <SOME HTML>
    }
});
```

And I would use this directive to add form fields to my page as follows:

```
<form-field field="some_data" type="text" name="other_data"></form-field>
```

I was using the `type` variable to differentiate between dateTime input, text input, numbers, etc, as they were distinguished in my code by only one keyword (by the input's `type` attribute.)

However now I have encountered a need to include checkboxes, which, thanks to my layout, require significantly different code to be structured properly. Based on this, when the type "checkbox" is passed into the directive I would like to return a different template value. I have tried variations of this kind of thing:

```
app.directive("formField", function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            fieldData: '=field',
            fieldName: '=name',
            fieldType: '=type'
        },
        template: function () {
            if(fieldType == 'checkbox') {
                return <CHECKBOX HTML>;
            } else {
                return <REGULAR FIELD HTML>;
        }
    }
});
```

This doesn't work. Can anybody tell me how to check the value coming in for the type field so that I can compare it in the directive's returned object? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the template, you can check for the element's attributes.

Your template should look like:

```
template: function (element, attrs) {
        if(attrs.type == 'checkbox') {
            return <CHECKBOX HTML>;
        } else {
            return <REGULAR FIELD HTML>;
        }
    }
```

The isolate scope attribute definitions for fieldData, fieldName, and fieldType are available in the template return string (using expressions), but they are not available in the template's logic. Ex:

```
template: '<p>{{ fieldData }}</p>'
```